# IndexOutOfBoundsException when BorderPane.setLeft

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

The error appears sometimes when I try to do a setLeft in a BorderPane.
The problem comes from the following line:

```
bpDetail.setLeft(selected ? ivSelected : null);
```

I want to draw an image when something is selected to the left of the borderPane, but sometimes the program throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane$BorderPositionProperty.invalidated(BorderPane.java:673)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.setLeft(BorderPane.java:314)
    at main.Selectable.showSelected(Selectable.java:594)
    at main.Selectable.initialize(Selectable.java:300)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 14 more
```

Does anyone understand why this happens sometimes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which values can the ivSelected take? (1 to 3)?

Comment: Always is the same image:
@FXML
  private ImageView ivSelected;

Comment: I sorry, looking into the API I get it now

Comment: Could you provide a minimal running example which causes the error?

Comment: just in case you are unsure what @Sztyler suggests: read [mcve] and act accordingly :)